# Modify dependencies on installed rpm package

Tags: rpm, yum

I have installed a rpm package builded by myself whichs depends on php-common. Now, I need to install a new php-common version. Since it will remove php-common (current version) yum is telling me to remove my rpm-package.
I don't want to remove this package since I already know it will not be any problem with the new php-common version. How can I avoid yum to remove o check for dependencies on my rpm package?

An example of what I'm doing:

**Installed packages:**
mypackage.rpm (require php-common)
php-common.rpm

When installing *php56w-common* it says it conflicts with *php-common.rpm* which I can not remove because it will try to remove also mypackage.rpm. I would like to remove php-common.rpm but keep installed (even with broken dependencies) mypackage.rpm

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with `yum`. Correct way to do this would be to rebuild `mypackage.rpm` to have a requirement that both `php-common` and `php56w-common` provide.

If you do `rpm -q --provides php-common`, you would see a list of names that this package provides, find the same thing for `php56w-common` and use

```
 Requires: <name>
```

in `mypackage.rpm` when you build it.

If the above is out of reach, then one can try using `rpm` cmdline. Remove `php-common` forcefully and install `php56w-common`.

```
$ rpm -q php-common  # This finds the name of the package installed on the system
$ rpm -e --nodeps <name>
$ rpm -ivh php56w-common.rpm  # php56w-common.rpm needs to be present on disk.
```